# Rotate left side

Tags: algorithm, integer

I have an integer.
Suppose n=25314; 
I want to rotate the digits on the left side of an integer(n) n times.
`For ex. int=25314 and 3 time rotate left side .so, result is int=14253
int =32546 and 4 time rotate left side .So, result is int=63254`
How do I rotate an integer left side with nth times in c++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1234567 / 1000 = 1234, with remainder 567.
Then just put them back together in the reverse order.
You do need to calculate x, which is the power of 10 higher than d.
(That's the loop.)

```
int n = 1234567;
int p = (int)pow(10, 3); // if you want to rotate by 3 digits
int d = n / p; // = 1234
int r = n - d * p; // = 567
int x = 1;
while(x <= d) x *= 10; // = 10000
int result = r * x + d; // = 5670000 + 1234 = 5671234
```

Comment: @Moo: I should be werkin'

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the integer into a string.  Do a substring from beginning to n and a substring from n+1 to the end of the string.  Concatenate them together with the right chunk first and the left chunk second. Then convert the string back to integer.

Comment: There's also the `std::rotate` algorithm to do the subchunk steps: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf7418325eb5a876

Answer (score 0):

For a N digit integer, and you want to rotate it left M times, the most simple way is to do a modular operation M % N, that will give you the final shift of each digit.

For example in you question, you would like to rotate 32546 left 4 digits, 4 % 5 is 4, so each digit need to be rotated left 4 digits.

number: 32546, digits: 5, rotate count: 4, shift for each digit: 4 % 5 = 4

```
number:  original position   final position
  3              4            (4+4)%5 = 3
  2              3            (3+4)%5 = 2
  5              2            (2+4)%5 = 1
  4              1            (1+4)%5 = 0
  6              0            (0+4)%5 = 4
```

So, the final result is : 63254

For very big integers, you could convert the integer to a string, do rotate and change it back. But, for this case, you can do like this:

```
int result = 32645;
for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)
    result *= 10;          // this is to rotate left 4 digits 
int right = 32546;
for(int i=0; i<5-4; ++i)
    right /= 10;           // get the number to be appended to the right;
result += right;
result %= 100000;         // get the final 5 digit result;
```